# jQuery to hide divs that don't match selected classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to filter through some product search results. 
There are various types of filters one could use to dig through the results (color, type, size, etc) and I would like to make it impossible to end up with "no results" through the filters by hiding the ones that do not have any content as filters are engaged.

I suppose another way of phrasing my question would be that I'm trying to verify what filters should exist before allowing the user to activate them.

For example in the sample code, if #brnd_B was selected and no products contained .prdbx.brnd_B.ptype_C, then #ptype_C should be disabled so the user cannot select it.

The #col_Red option should be disabled once any of the filters are engaged since it doesn't exist within the products list. #cat_C sould be disabled for the same reason.

Then the appropriate .prdbx boxes should display after filtering, obviously.

```
Sample Code:

<h1>Brands</h1>
<input type="radio" class="bFilter filterSwitch" name="bFilter" id="brnd_A">
<input type="radio" class="bFilter filterSwitch" name="bFilter" id="brnd_B">
<input type="radio" class="bFilter filterSwitch" name="bFilter" id="brnd_C">

<h1>Types</h1>
<input type="radio" class="pTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="pTypeFilter" id="ptype_A">
<input type="radio" class="pTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="pTypeFilter" id="ptype_B">
<input type="radio" class="pTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="pTypeFilter" id="ptype_C">

<h1>Options</h1>
<input type="radio" class="bTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="bTypeFilter" id="cat_A">
<input type="radio" class="bTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="bTypeFilter" id="cat_B">
<input type="radio" class="bTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="bTypeFilter" id="cat_C">

<h1>Colors</h1>
<input type="radio" class="cTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="cTypeFilter" id="col_Black">
<input type="radio" class="cTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="cTypeFilter" id="col_Blue">
<input type="radio" class="cTypeFilter filterSwitch" name="cTypeFilter" id="col_Red">

<h1>Products</h1>
<div class="prdbx show brnd_A cat_B ptype_C col_Black yld_Standard mod_PIXMAiP4820  mod_PIXMAiX6520  mod_PIXMAiX6550">Data 1</div>
<div class="prdbx show brnd_B cat_A ptype_A col_Blue yld_Standard mod_PIXMAiX6520">Data 2</div>
<div class="prdbx show brnd_A cat_A ptype_B col_Black yld_Standard mod_PIXMAiP4820">Data 3</div>
```

This is the jQuery I have so far; it's displaying the appropriate .prdbx's for the most part, but it never "verifies the radio button should be allowed" before displaying them, which is what I'm struggling with.

If I make the sep variable a comma, I get mixed results, as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $('.filterSwitch').click(function(e) {
        $('.brandbx').hide();
        $('.prdbx').hide(); // hide all products
        // set up variables
        thisFilter1 = "";
        var sep = ""
        // hide inapplicable filters

        // figure out what we're displaying
        $('input[name=bFilter]:checked').each(function(e) {
            thisFilter1 = thisFilter1 + sep + '.'+this.id;
        });
        $('input[name=bTypeFilter]:checked').each(function(e) {
            thisFilter1 = thisFilter1 + sep + '.'+this.id;
        });
        $('input[name=pTypeFilter]:checked').each(function(e) {
            thisFilter1 = thisFilter1 + sep + '.'+this.id;
        });
        $('.cTypeFilter').each(function(e) {
            thisFilter1 = thisFilter1 + sep + '.'+this.id;
        });

        $(thisFilter1).show();
        verifyEmpty();
    });

    function verifyEmpty(){
        var totalFilter = 0;
        $('input[name=bFilter]:checked').each(function(e) {
            totalFilter++;
        });
        $('.cTypeFilter:checked').each(function(e) {
            totalFilter++;
        });
        $('.pTypeFilter:checked').each(function(e) {
            totalFilter++;
        });
        $('.bTypeFilter:checked').each(function(e) {
            totalFilter++;
        });
        if(totalFilter == 0){
            $('.prdbx').show(); // show all products    
            $('.brandbx').show(); // show models
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! I'm definitely interested in any ways to make it function better while being cleaner! Thanks again =)

Comment: just took another look and my assumption about what you are trying to do is wrong... i did notice that you are getting all c options though instead of just selected (so unless a product has all colors, it wouldnt get displayed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code

```
$('.filterSwitch').each(function(){
if($("."+this.id).length<=0)
    this.disabled=true;
});
```

This is considering that even if one radio button is selected and others are blank it should filter the values(as your code works now).
If its not the case & you want all the radio buttons to be selected before filtering then the code will be different.

Comment: Hmm this initially seemingly had no effect on my code; since the div's are only being toggled with visibility, I modified your suggestion to `if($("."+this.id+":visible").length<=0){` but now every single radio button gets disabled, even the active one. Any ideas?

Comment: `$('.filterSwitch').each(function(){
    if($("."+this.id).is(":visible").length<=0){
     this.disabled=true;
    }
   });` isn't doing anything seemingly, either

Comment: I'm putting the code directly before the `$(thisFilter1).show();` line by the way

Comment: Ah ha! Putting `$('.filterSwitch').each(function(){if($("."+this.id+":visible").length<=0)this.disabled=true;
});` AFTER `$(thisFilter1).show();` has seemingly done it! I'll let you know if I run into any other questions! Thanks again!

Comment: Dont keep the code  inside click event or any function, just keep it in ready block or simply outside